# Pandas how to apply a function that takes two arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pipeline

I have a pandas dataframe that contains a date column where the dates are stored as strings:

```
0    2021-12-04
1    2021-12-01
2    2021-11-29
3    2021-11-15
4    2021-11-06
Name: date, dtype: object
```

I have a solution that uses variable assignment:

```
df['date'] = df.apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['date'], '%Y-%m-%d'), axis=1)
```

But since this transformation is part of a data pipeline, I want to use the `assign` method. I tried:

```
df.assign(date=df['date'].apply(datetime.strptime('%Y-%m-%d')))
```

But this produces an error: `KeyError: 'date'`.

I suspect this is because the values from the `date` column aren't being passed to `datetime.strptime('%Y-%m-%d')`. What is the best way to solve this error?

Comment: Will you please show a sample of your dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) instead of `apply` + `lambda` + `datetime.strptime`:

```
df.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d'))
```